# c# net2.0 Console App merge arguments in one single string

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have one console app which receives a variable number of arguments. I need to remove the first element (args[0]) and merge all the others into a single string.

How I can do that in .NET 2.0?

Comment: So what is the problem? Do that in a `for` or `foreach` loop if that is what you require further on in your code. Or is there another constraint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string result = string.Join(" ", args, 1, args.Count-1);
```

This concatenates all the arguments but the first, separating them with spaces.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

If you need a delimiter:

```
string delim = "%";
string merge = args[1];

for (int i = 2; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    merge = delim + args[i];
}
```

If you don't need a delimiter:

```
args[0] = "";
string merge = String.Join("", args);
```